# insert into one table from another table using join update or insert SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, insert-select

I currently have two tables as seen in the pictures below.

The first table is called `bottle`:

[image]

The second table is called `cases`:

[image]

I am trying to insert into the bottles table where case_id = 0 the values seen in the cases table (ie case_id=100, 100, 103, 103 etc..). They are two separate tables and I am trying to join them without creating `NULL` values.

Please let me know if I need to use insert, join, or update. I would manually do it however these data points are coming live from a PLC and there will be many more than just all the data points seen below.

Comment: Can You Post your table structures with out images?

Comment: `I am trying to join them` ... what logic do you want to use to bring in these new values, as there is no explicit join column?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit join column with which to perform the `UPDATE` you want.  But we can create one by joining on the row number value from each table, using a certain order.  In the query below, I order the row number in the `bottle` table using the `bottle_id`, and the row number in the `cases` table using the `case_id`.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.case_id = t2.case_id
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bottle_id) rowId
    FROM bottle t
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY case_id) rowId
    cases t
) t2
    ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
```

This should give output in `bottle` looking like this (some columns omitted):

```
bottle_id      case_id
1              100
2              100
3              103
4              103
5              104
6              104
7              105
8              105
```